# Why is this php array not returning an error?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, matrix, foreach

```
<?php

$letters = array( 'A', 'B', 'C' );
$numbers = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$matrix = array( 'Letter' => $letters, 'Number' => $numbers );

echo "<p>Start : {$matrix['Letter'][0]}</p>";

foreach($matrix as $array => $list)
{
   echo'<ul>';
   foreach($list as $key => $value)
   { 
      echo "<li>$array [$key] = $value";
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

I need help understanding this code, essentially I am confused how line #13 is working.

```
What I see:

'$value' = non-key values of '$list'
'$list' = non-key values of '$matrix'
'$matrix' = $letters, $numbers

Therefore '$value' = $letters, $numbers

'$array' = key values of '$list'

Therefore '$array' = 'Letter', 'Number'
```

I know I can type `echo "<p>Letter: {$letters[0]}</p>";` to have the letter 'A' returned, but if I type `echo "<p>Letter: {$letters}</p>";` then I will receive an error.

My focus is on line 13, `{ echo "<li>$array [$key] = $value"; }`

Why is this not returning an error?

No spot in `'$array'` was specified, `'$key'` was never assigned, and no spot in `'$value'` is specified.

I have only started learning PHP & MySQL a few days ago.
Any help is greatly appreciated as I am trying to learn and want to move on to the next part of this book, but I need to get my head around this first.

~Thanks!

Comment: `$key`, `$value` and `$array` are defined in the foreach

Comment: `$array` is defined in the outer foreach loop

Comment: you cannot echo on array that's why it produce error when you do `echo "<p>Letter: {$letters}</p>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($matrix as $array => $list)
{
    //$array is String "Letter" and $list is array $letters for first iteration
    //$array is String "Number" and $list is array $numbers for second iteration

    echo'<ul>';
    foreach($list as $key => $value)
    {
       //when $list=$letters 
       //1st iteration:$key =0 and value 'A'; 2nd iteration :$key=1 and $value= 'B'.....

      //finally
      //$array means "Letter"
      //$key mean 0
      //$value  mean "A"

      //and loop goes on


        echo "<li>$array [$key] = $value";
         //result
         //<li>Letter[0] = A;
         //<li>Letter[1] = B;  
         //.............
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Hope you understand.
Remember your li tag is not closed.Use this

```
echo "<li>$array [$key] = $value </li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

All three of those variables are ones that have been temporarily defined for the body of a loop by the `foreach` construct, and each of them are numbers or strings, not arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($matrix as $array => $list)
```

The above line defines the variables `$array` and `$list` for the body of that loop; `$array` is a string that is set to each of the keys of `$matrix` in turn; `$list` is the corresponding value for each key.

```
foreach($list as $key => $value)
```

Similarly, this defines the variables `$key` and `$value` within the body of the loop; `$key` is set to each key of `$list` one at a time, and `$value` is set to each matching value.

Answer (score 1):

All of those three variables are scalar values (either strings or numbers), so there's no issue with printing them directly.

```
foreach($matrix as $array => $list)
```

Look at how [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works. Here the not-well-named `$array` will have one of two values: either `"Letter"` or `"Number"`. Obviously both of them can be printed without issue.

```
foreach($list as $key => $value)
```

Here `$list` will either be `array( 'A', 'B', 'C' )` or `( 1, 2, 3 )`. In either case, `$key` will have one of the values `0`, `1` or `2` and `$value` will be either a string or an integer. Again, all of these can be printed with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this

```
echo "<p>Letter: {$letters}</p>";
```

returns error because you tried to echo whole array. It can't be done with echo.

This code

```
foreach($list as $key => $value)
{ echo "<li>$array [$key] = $value"; }
echo '</ul>';
}
```

is valid because every value has it's own key. If you don't define key for some value, then the key will added automatically. 
You said you know that this works:

```
echo "<p>Letter: {$letters[0]}</p>";
```

"0" is the key and it was added automatically during the array initialization. Key doesn't need to be string to be a key for some value.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the fact that if no key value was set for `'$letters'` and `'$numbers'`, their key for each value is their order by default.

So going through each loop I realized that `$list[0] = $letters` and `$list[1] = $numbers`

```
Therefore:
'$value' = non key value of '$list[0]' = non-key value of '$letters'
'$key' = key value of '$list[0]' = key value of '$letters'
```

So in a sense, `'$list'` is a pointer to `'$letters'` and `'$numbers'` respectively.

If anyone in the future ever gets confused, I have worked out each iteration below:

```
/*

Loop One:
Sub1:
$list[0] = $letters = 'A', 'B', 'C'
$key = '0'
$value = 'A'

Sub2:
$list[0] = $letters = 'A', 'B', 'C'
$key = '1'
$value = 'B'

Sub3:
$list[0] = $letters = 'A', 'B', 'C'
$key = '2'
$value = 'C'

Loop Two:
Sub1:
$list[1] = $numbers = '1', '2', '3'
$key = '0'
$value = '1'

Sub2:
$list[1] = $numbers = '1', '2', '3'
$key = '1'
$value = '2'

Sub3:
$list[1] = $numbers = '1', '2', '3'
$key = '2'
$value = '3'

*/
```